# generating html from xml+xslt from jdeveloper

Tags: java, xml, xslt, jdeveloper

When I am trying to generate HTML from XML+XSLT in jdeveloper 10g using a java class I am getting following error

```
XML-22108: (Error) Invalid Source - URL format is incorrect.

XML-22000: (Fatal Error) Error while parsing XSL file (no protocol: headerMenu.xsl)
```

But when I am compiling the file with another jdk from command line it is working fine.

Following is my code snippet

```
 TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();

        Transformer transformer = 
            tFactory.newTransformer(new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource(xslHeaderMenu)); //takes the xsl

             System.out.println("...xsl for header navigation menu block included...");

        transformer.transform(new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource(xmlDataFile), 
                              new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult(new FileOutputStream(htmlHeaderMenu))); //takes the xml and generates html for header menu
```

Please advice how can I generate inside jdeveloper

Comment: What is in xslHeaderMenu and xmlDataFile?

Comment: String xslHeaderMenu = "headerMenu.xsl";
String xslLeftMenu = "leftMenu.xsl";

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the javadoc for StreamSource, the string method says that it 'Must be a String that conforms to the URI syntax', which you 'headerMenu.xsl' isn't.

I would try:

```
tFactory.newTransformer(
  new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource(
    new File(xslHeaderMenu))); //takes the xsl
```

as File can take an abstract filename (also for the other streamsource)